# Meaningful data from text file powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a text file which looks something  like below, try to get meaningful data by doing replace, using wild card characters, but not quite getting it right.

```
 computer  - server1
 Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS  junk data
 Volume 2     C                NTFS  junk data 
 Volume 3         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS    junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF99XY2_APP01_ABCD_LH\
 Volume 4     H   R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS       junk data
 Volume 5         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF99XY2_DBE01_EFGH_LH\
 Volume 10         R6T3_ABCDEF  NTFS  junk data
   H:\R6X3_ABCDEF99XY2_QRS_IJKL_LH\
 Volume 7         R5T2_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X2_ABCDEF99XY2_QWE__MNOP_LH\
 Volume 8         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF99XY2_BTE___0DF8_LH\
 computer  - server2
 Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS  junk data
 Volume 2     C                NTFS  junk data 
 Volume 3         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS    junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF88XY2_APP01_ABCD_LH\
 Volume 4     H   R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS       junk data
 Volume 5         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF88XY2_DBE01_EFGH_LH\
 Volume 10         R6T3_ABCDEF  NTFS  junk data
   H:\R6X3_ABCDEF88XY2_QRS_IJKL_LH\
 Volume 7         R5T2_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X2_ABCDEF88XY2_QWE__MNOP_LH\
 Volume 8         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF88XY2_BTE___0DF8_LH\
```

This is the output I am looking for : 1) get those volumes with a letter next to them(like volumes 2,4).
2) get those volumes with no letter next to them, the line below it which is not a volume line (like volumes 3,5,6). 3) remove those volumes with no letter nor a non-volume line below them (like volume 1).

Eventually, output looks like:

```
computer1 Volume 2  C
computer1 Volume 3  H:\R5X1_ABCDEF99XY2_APP01_ABCD_LH\
computer1 Volume 4  H
computer1 Volume 5  H:\R5X1_ABCDEF99XY2_DBE01_EFGH_LH\
computer1 Volume 10 H:\R6X3_ABCDEF99XY2_QRS_IJKL_LH\
computer2 Volume 2  C
computer2 Volume 3  H:\R5X1_ABCDEF88XY2_APP01_ABCD_LH\
computer2 Volume 2  H
computer2 Volume 3  H:\R5X1_ABCDEF88XY2_DBE01_EFGH_LH\
computer2 Volume 4  H:\R6X3_ABCDEF88XY2_QRS_IJKL_LH\
computer2 Volume 10 H:\R6X3_ABCDEF88XY2_QRS_IJKL_LH\
```

**Edit** Example code from comment:

im a bit stuck on the conditions tht need to be used :

```
$FileListArray2 = @()
Foreach($file in Get-Content $FilesName | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "(junk1)|(junk2)"}) { 
    if($file -match "(Volume)") { } 
    $FileListArray2 += ,@($file2) 
} 
$FileListArray2
```

Please note that here I have left the condition bit empty, i have tried some stuff for that but its not quite working the way i want

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: im a bit stuck on the conditions tht need to be used :

$FileListArray2 = @()
Foreach($file in Get-Content $FilesName | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "(junk1)|(junk2)"})

    {   


if($file -match "(Volume)")
{
}

$FileListArray2 += ,@($file2)


      
    } 
$FileListArray2  Please note that here I have left the condition bit empty, i have tried some stuff for tht but its not quite working the way i want

Comment: Please edit your post with the code that you have tried so that it is legible.

Comment: sorry for not adding the code peoperly - thanks zdan for doing it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

**UPDATED:**

```
$inputstring = @'
 computer  - server1
 Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS  junk data
 Volume 2     C                NTFS  junk data 
 Volume 3         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS    junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF99XY2_APP01_ABCD_LH\
 Volume 4     H   R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS       junk data
 Volume 5         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF99XY2_DBE01_EFGH_LH\
 Volume 10         R6T3_ABCDEF  NTFS  junk data
   H:\R6X3_ABCDEF99XY2_QRS_IJKL_LH\
 Volume 7         R5T2_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X2_ABCDEF99XY2_QWE__MNOP_LH\
 Volume 8         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF99XY2_BTE___0DF8_LH\
 computer  - server2
 Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS  junk data
 Volume 2     C                NTFS  junk data 
 Volume 3         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS    junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF88XY2_APP01_ABCD_LH\
 Volume 4     H   R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS       junk data
 Volume 5         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF88XY2_DBE01_EFGH_LH\
 Volume 10         R6T3_ABCDEF  NTFS  junk data
   H:\R6X3_ABCDEF88XY2_QRS_IJKL_LH\
 Volume 7         R5T2_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X2_ABCDEF88XY2_QWE__MNOP_LH\
 Volume 8         R5T1_ABCDEF  NTFS   junk data
   H:\R5X1_ABCDEF88XY2_BTE___0DF8_LH\
'@

# Split the input into an array of strings
$lines = $inputstring -split '[\r\n]'

# Setup patterns to match against
$pattern1 = "(Volume \d+)\s+(\w)\s+"
$pattern2 = "(Volume \d+)\s+"
$pattern3 = "\s+(\w:\\.*)"
$pattern4 = "^ computer  - (\S+)$"

# Store the current computer that is being viewed
$currentcomputer = "UNKNOWN"

# Loop through each line
for($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.count; $i++)
{
    # Start off assuming the current line produces no output
    $output = ""

    # Look for volumes with drive letters
    if($lines[$i] -match $pattern1)
    {
        $output = $matches[1] + " " + $matches[2]
    }
    # Look for volumes without drive letters
    elseif($lines[$i] -match $pattern2)
    {
        $volume = $matches[1]

        # Consider the next line to see if it has a path
        if($lines[$i + 1] -match $pattern3)
        {
            $output = $volume + " " + $matches[1]

            # If the next line had a path then we handled it and need to skip it
            $i++
        }
    }
    elseif($lines[$i] -match $pattern4)
    {
        $currentcomputer = $matches[1]
    }

    # Write out any output that was produced
    if($output -ne "")
    {
        $currentcomputer + " " + $output
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Is there however a way to do this without splitting the lines. The reason I say this is because, I have this list for various computers. And hence I have strings with computer names in between this text at various places which get lost in the splitting.

Comment: Can you please give an example? I'm not seeing why my response wouldn't just skip over those lines (which seems like the correct thing to do).

Comment: Perhaps my code just needs to pattern to match lines that just have hostnames on them and output them if you do want that output.

Comment: if the input string had lines in between with computer names , say "computer ABC", and then after a few lines, "computer XYZ" etc. Along with the above details, I am looking to pull out the computer names too..Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your prompt responses

Comment: OK, I'm sure that's not a problem to do accommodate for and I'd be happy to update my answer. However, before I spend time on the solution I'd really like to see a sample input of what you have and and sample output of what you'd like. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the code above..thank you once again for your prompt responses